# How to redirect to Sign In page after log off while using IdentityServices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I have used Thinktecture identity services to authenticate users on my MVC website.
I use following code to allow users to log out.

```
FederationConfiguration cfg = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration;
    var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
    fam.SignOut(false);
    var signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm);
    return new RedirectResult(signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString());
```

This successfully logs user out of the identity services but how can I redirect user to Sing In page, rather than displaying a Successful Sign out message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to change the signout endpoint in IdentityServer.